# Should I start a new question or modify the existing one, if the issue is relevant to yet another desktop environment?

Tags: discussion

I'm seeing duplicate icons for Telegram messenger in LXDE. I found a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/785982/how-can-i-fix-duplicate-icons-for-telegram) asking just that, but for another window managers: XFCE and MATE.

What should I do to get an answer for LXDE desktop environment: start a new question or modify the existing one? (how?)

I'm afraid that my question won't get many views if I modify the existing question. Besides, all those who already viewed it and considered answering the question, considered answering the original question, not the one extended for LXDE.

Answer (score 7):

The question you linked to is my question and I'd like to help if I can. I am not sure if the accepted solution works on Xfce; it's only for MATE - apologies to everyone for the lack of clarity.

However, this is not the solution I actually use. I answered this question:

[Two Telegram messengers in the Unity Launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/719933/two-telegram-messengers-in-the-unity-launcher/795449#795449)

with the method I do use now - I rename the `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications` so that only the `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications` gets used. This solution works for any DE (although it needs to be re-done each time Telegram gets updated).

Since we have a question about Unity and one about MATE, both with DE specific answers, I think you should feel free to ask a new question, and I should edit my question to ask only about MATE since I can't verify the answer works in Xfce. I will also add a link to the Unity post so that the DE-agnostic <strike>hack</strike> solution is easy to find. You might even attract a much better answer that solves it permanently for all flavors.

Comment: The solution in the linked question doesn't solve the problem for me in Lubuntu. I'll go ask a separate question.